# Sea devil description

Tags: word-choice

Do "lamp" and "torch" work in #1 or only "lamp-like" "torch-like" appendage? And do native speakers use "face" when they talk about "fish" and "animals"?

> 1. "A sea devil is a fish with a torch-like appendage on its front."
> 2. "It's a fish with a spine (or "fishing rod") pointing straight up with a "lamp" or "fishing lure" dangling in from its end."

Comment: Is there any part that you were particularly concerned about?

Comment: I thought the second example is wordy.

Comment: Do "lamp" and "torch" work in #1 or only "lamp-like" "torch-like" appendage? And  do native speakers use "face" when they talk about "fish" and "animals"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of scare quotes to say "lamp" indicates that you are using the word in a technical or non-literal way.  If you write:

> It has a "lamp" on a "fishing-rod".

You mean

> It has a thing that I will call a *lamp* on a thing that I will call a *fishing rod*

You are defining these terms and marking them as being different from the normal, non-technical usage. The quote marks show that you don't mean "a vessel containing flammable liquid and a wick"

It is quite common and non-technical to describe the part of an animal with eyes and mouth as its face.

> Whether you love or hate spiders, Jorge Farfan’s extreme closeups of their faces will likely reinforce your feelings. ([source](https://weather.com/science/news/beautifully-creepy-photos-show-spider-faces-close-20140709))

Answer (score 1):

A sea devil refers to a [black seadevil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_seadevil), so if what you are trying to describe looks like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_seadevil#/media/File:Humpback_anglerfish.png), then those descriptions are correct. If you were trying to ask if the descriptions were grammatically correct, I do not see any grammatical issues with either of the descriptions.

Comment: I was wondering if using "torch" in quotes would also work instead of "lamp"?  "It's a fish with a spine pointing straight up with a "torch"  dangling in from its end." And "A sea devil is a fish with a torch-like appendage on the  front part of its face."